# Prevent thread from exiting VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a thread in my project that handles FileSystem events (FileSystemWatcher) and raises an event when a file is created.

The problem I am facing is that, as soon as I execute this thread, it ends. For some reason, after the code is executed to start the FileSystemWatcher, the thread imminently exists (believing it has already executed all the code), and therefore no events can be raised.

I proposed a solution using the following code:

```
     Do While True
        Application.DoEvents()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    Loop
```

This works because it prevents the thread from exiting, so it may continue with the events, and the FileSystemWatcher properly raises events when files are created.

However, I do not believe this is a sustainable method for ensuring the events are raised, as it uses more resources and seems like taking a shortcut.

Is there a way to properly ensure the thread remains running, so the FileSystemWatcher can raise events properly?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Calling `Application.DoEvents()` is bad. In this case though it's doing nothing as it's not running on the UI thread.

Comment: It's bad in general, but calling `DoEvents()` in a thread is just asking for trouble. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to initialize the `FileSystemWatcher` on a thread?
I think you do not need a separate thread for this.

But you can handle the fired events asynchronously with Async/Await.

```vb
Private Shared Async Sub OnChanged(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Await Task.Delay(1000)
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course the `Task.Delay(1000)` is just an example method call inside the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Add FileSystemWatcher1 to your form. In the properties for FileSystemWatcher1 set EnableRaisingEvents to True, modify the filter to account for the file(s) you want to look for (i.e *.txt or *.* or whatever you are watching for), set the NotifyFilter to "FileName, LastWrite", and specify the path you want to watch.

In your code add...

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Watcher As FileSystemWatcher = FileSystemWatcher1
    AddHandler Watcher.Created, AddressOf OnCreated
    Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True  'already configured in the control, but why not
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnCreated(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)

    'Actions to perform when file is created

End Sub
```